# ATBSWP, Chapter 3, Collatz Sequence. Why does the while loop run when condition is already met?

Tags: python, collatz

if the user inputs the number 1, then the while loop shouldn't run since 1 = 1, correct?

```
def collatz(number):

    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2

    elif number % 2 == 1:
        result = 3 * number + 1
        print(result)
        return result

try:
    n = input('Give me a number: ') #user inputs number, saved to n
    while n != 1: #function repeats while number is not equal to 1
        n = collatz(int(n)) #this is what actually calls the function
except ValueError:
    print('Please use whole numbers only.')
```

Comment: You have `int(n)` in the wrong place, `n = '1'` is not the same a `n = 1`, try `n = int(input(...))`

Comment: ah gotcha. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, the type of n is considered as str so "1" != 1
hence the condition is satisfied.
Look at this example https://code.hackerearth.com/0acb47j

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you!

Comment: To get desired output you have to typecast n to int.

Comment: i haven't learned typecasting yet but I will look into it. Thank you!

Comment: n = int(n)  will do the job.